# How can I cite three papers of different years, by one author? e.g. Smith(1990, 1995, 2001)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and BibTeX so I apologise in advance if I'm missing information or this seems like it should be simple!

I have three papers by one author which I would like to cite in the text such as "

> as specified by Smith (1990, 1995, 2001)

but have as three separate references in the bibliography.

Is there a way to do this? I am using the `ametsoc` bibliography style at the moment, and can't seem to find a solution other than citing it as `[Smith(1990), Smith(1995, Smith(2001)]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded a citation management package such as `natbib` with a command such as

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

and assuming further the three entries have been given the "keys" `smith:1990`, `smith:1995`, and `smith:2001`, you could issue the command

```
\cite{smith:1990, smith:2001, smith:1995} % note: entries needn't be sorted chronologically
```

to generate a citation of the form

> Smith (1990, 1995, 2001)

The `natbib` package will sort the arguments of the `\cite` command chronologically.

(If you were using the `harvard` citation management package, you'd type `\citeasnoun{smith:1990, smith:2001, smith:1995}` to get the same result.)

Comment: The user uses `ametsoc` which is compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Apologies for the missing info, I am indeed using the `natbib` package. My references in my .bib file are as such:

`"@ARTICLE{Smith1990,
AUTHOR="J. Smith",
TITLE="Meteorology Stuff",
JOURNAL="AMS Journal",
VOLUME= "1",
PAGES= "1-10",
YEAR=1990
}`

and of course the other two, with different years, titles etc. I am not sure how to use `\cite{}` to have it call just the years. Experimenting with your example gives me "??" when i run pdflatex and bibtex. I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

Comment: @CoffeeBean - Does `\cite{Smith1990, Smith2001, Smith1995}` (note the uppercasing/lowercasing matters) work, possibly after blowing away the `.aux` and `.bbl` files and then running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on your main source file?

Comment: @Mico - Thanks, yes it does! I tried this initially but was having some problems with the `ametsoc` style anyway and it didn't seem this simple. This has helped clear up how some of this works for me thankfully!

Comment: @CoffeeBean - Glad to learn you're up and running! Please feel free to upvote and/or accept/checkmark my answer. ;-)

Comment: @Mico Yes! Certainly, I knew there was something else I meant to do...